# Acumatica Extending PMProjectStatusEx

Tags: acumatica

I am working on the Project Budget Screen of acumatica, the screen uses the  table PMProjectStatusEx which is a Projection table of PMProjectStatus. So I extended the PMProjectStatus table and added a field in there, I also extended the PMProjectStatusEx to add the same field and added it to the screen. But unlike the standard fields that updates the physical table PMProjectStatus my added field does not update the physical table. What could be the reason for this? Below is my code

Thanks

```
public class PMProjectStatusExt : 
PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.PM.PMProjectStatus>
{
  #region UsrMarkupPct
  public abstract class usrMarkupPct : PX.Data.IBqlField
  {
  }
  protected Decimal? _UsrMarkupPct;
  [PXDBDecimal(6, MinValue = 0, MaxValue = 1000)]
  //[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Markup %")]
  public virtual Decimal? UsrMarkupPct
  {
      get
      {
          return this._UsrMarkupPct;
      }
      set
      {
          this._UsrMarkupPct = value;
      }
  }
  #endregion


public class PMProjectStatusExExt : 
PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.PM.PMProjectStatusEx>
  {
      #region UsrMarkupPct
      public abstract class usrMarkupPct : PX.Data.IBqlField
      {
      }
      protected Decimal? _UsrMarkupPct;
      [PXDBDecimal(6, MinValue = 0, MaxValue = 1000, BqlField = typeof(PMProjectStatusExt.usrMarkupPct))]
      [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Markup %")]
      public virtual Decimal? UsrMarkupPct
      {
          get
          {
              return this._UsrMarkupPct;
          }
          set
          {
              this._UsrMarkupPct = value;
          }
      }
      #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add fields using the DATA ACCESS section of the Project Editor it will generate DB Scripts to update the table behind the scene:
[image]

[image]

When you add fields using a DAC extension in CODE section, it will not generate the DB Scripts.

In that case you need to manually add the scripts in DB Scripts section.

**EDIT**

One way to manually add DB field in DB Scripts is:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Sys.Columns WHERE Name = N'UsrMarkupPct' and 
              Object_ID = Object_ID(N'PMProjectStatus'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE PMProjectStatus ADD UsrMarkupPct DECIMAL(19,6)
END
GO
```