# Filter Inventory by cross reference

Tags: acumatica

I want to customize the filtering of inventory by cross reference along with other properties.

I have added two other cross reference items for a stock item like this.

[image]

And now I want to customize, inventory filter in any other forms by the Alternate Type's Alternate Id value.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to add search capabilities over Stock Item's Alternate IDs without a customization. Also, keep in mind that we are talking here about the one-to-many relationship between Stock Item and Alternate IDs, which makes it impossible to simply drop Alternate ID column into the Inventory ID selector as this will result in same Stock Item shown multiple times because of a necessary join with the Cross-Reference DAC.

The first thing you need to do is create a database-bound field for the InventoryItem DAC (***make sure you create UsrAlternateIDs column in the InventoryItem database***) table to concatenate all Alternate IDs of a Stock Item (***notice Visibility set to PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible on PXUIField - this is required to show Alternate IDs column inside the Inventory ID selector***):

```
public class InventoryItemExt : PXCacheExtension<InventoryItem>
{
    public abstract class usrAlternateIDs : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(4000, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Alternate IDs", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public string UsrAlternateIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Next step is to override the Persist method in the InventoryItemMaint BLC extension to regenerate concatenated Alternate IDs every time the user makes changes in the Cross-Reference tab :

```
public class InventoryItemMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<InventoryItemMaint>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(Action del)
    {
        using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
        {
            InventoryItem item = Base.Item.Current;
            if (item != null && Base.itemxrefrecords.Cache.IsDirty)
            {
                string alternateIDs = string.Empty;
                foreach (INItemXRef crossRef in Base.itemxrefrecords.Select())
                {
                    alternateIDs = string.IsNullOrEmpty(alternateIDs) ?
                        crossRef.AlternateID : alternateIDs + "; " + crossRef.AlternateID;
                }
                item.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>().UsrAlternateIDs = alternateIDs;
                Base.Item.Update(item);
            }

            del();
            ts.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, you should add ***UsrAlternateIDs*** in PXSelector FastFilterFields property:
[image]

Once these 3 steps are completed, the final result should look as follows:
[image]

To concatenate all currently existing Stock Item Alternative IDs in one step, you can implement a custom action on the Stock Items screen. You can remove the action after that.

```
public class InventoryItemMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<InventoryItemMaint>
{
    ...

    public PXAction<InventoryItem> RecalcAlternateIDs;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Concatenate Alternate IDs")]
    protected void recalcAlternateIDs()
    {
        PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, () =>
        {
            InventoryItemMaint itemMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
            var items = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.stkItem, Equal<boolTrue>>>.Select(itemMaint);
            foreach (InventoryItem item in items)
            {
                itemMaint.Clear();
                itemMaint.Item.Current = item;
                itemMaint.itemxrefrecords.Cache.IsDirty = true;
                itemMaint.Actions.PressSave();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Error is different, but says same that the Column is Invalid. This is where I wanted to implement.

https://snag.gy/HrSURP.jpg

Comment: This is because you are missing InventoryItem.UsrAlternateIDs field in the database. When you add DAC field in  DATA ACCESS section of Acumatica Project Editor it will create the DB script to add the column automatically. When adding DAC extension in CODE section it doesn't create the field automatically. For more details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542627/acumatica-extending-pmprojectstatusex

Comment: One possible way to fix it is to add a DB Script like this in Acumatica Project Editor:
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Sys.Columns WHERE Name = N'UsrAlternateIDs' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'InventoryItem'))
BEGIN
 ALTER TABLE InventoryItem ADD UsrAlternateIDs NVARCHAR(4000)
END
GO

Comment: I added custom column by customizing DAC directly and it worked and all the other codes worked as you have told me to. Maybe I missed something on custom column part. Thanks.