# How to add a foreign key reference to the primary key selector control

Tags: acumatica

In the stock item screen, a custom grid is added.  The DAC for the custom grid contains InventoryItem.inventoryID.  That particular grid has a custom field in which the user wishes to search for, inside the inventory item selector control.  I refer to the primary Inventory Item selector control for the stock item screen.

In normal circumstances, the customization manager allows you to select a particular field, and add that to the grid which appears inside the selector control.  That is simple, since the field is a member of the same DAC.  But in my case, I wish to add a column from the related data view.  Since the primary data view has no knowledge of grid, the needed column is not available for selection.  Also there is a high probability that records will be repeated inside the selector control, since the relation is one to many.  This is acceptable.

**I try the following suggestions.**

**1)  use Cache_attached event handler, for InventoryItem.InventoryCD.**  
I add my own custom PXSelect statement which joins InventoryItem & CustomTable.  But an error occurs:  A foreign key reference cannot be created from the type 'PX.Data.PXSelectJoin`3[PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem (ect)

**2)  Declare data view delegate for Items which yields type InventoryItem & CustomDAC.**
  This approach returns no errors.  However I am unable to select the user field, in the field selection panel.

**3)  Create a Project on InventoryItem DAC and write a PXSelect to join the two tables.**  
 I am unsure if this is the correct approach.

I wish to know if anyone has suggestions
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45639399/3929852) to concatenate field values from a related data view into a custom text column inside the InventoryItem table.