# How to include a custom field into Full-Text Entity Index?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

The client wishes to use the universal search box, to search for values in a custom field. How can this be done?

In this case, I created a simple custom text field, for InventoryItem.  Currently, it is not visible in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's refer to the custom UsrAlternateIDs field created in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45639399/3929852) and include it into Acumatica's Full-Text Entity Index.

The only modification required to include UsrAlternateIDs field into Full-Text Entity Index is to replace the original declaration of **PXSearchableAttribute** used on the **NoteID** field in the **InventoryItem** DAC. As shown in the code snippet below, **UsrAlternateIDs** is now included into the ***fields*** type array passed as 3rd parameter to the new **PXSearchableAttribute** constructor:

```
[PXNonInstantiatedExtension]
public class InventoryItemExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem>
{
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXSearchableAttribute))]
    [PXSearchable(SM.SearchCategory.IN, "{0}: {1}", 
        new Type[] {
            typeof(InventoryItem.itemType),
            typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD) },
        new Type[] {
            typeof(InventoryItem.descr),
            typeof(InventoryItemExt.usrAlternateIDs) },
        NumberFields = new Type[] {
            typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
            typeof(InventoryItemExt.usrAlternateIDs) },
        Line1Format = "{0}{1}{2}", 
        Line1Fields = new Type[] {
            typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD),
            typeof(INItemClass.descr),
            typeof(InventoryItem.baseUnit) },
        Line2Format = "{0}", 
        Line2Fields = new Type[] {
            typeof(InventoryItem.descr) },
        WhereConstraint = typeof(Where<Current<InventoryItem.itemStatus>, 
            NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>>)
     )]
     public Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
}
```

After you implement an **InventoryItem** extension following the sample above and rebuild Full-Text Entity Index on your Acumatica ERP instance, it should be possible to search for Inventory Items based on their Alternate IDs.